# Sharing the $scope value between controller and directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that toggles a DIV I have using `ng-show`. Now when the DIV is visible after 5 seconds I wish it to fade out. The `ng-show` is toggled using a `$scope` variable in my controller (`$scope.showPopover`) which is a boolean, it is either true or false. This is my HTML:

Hello World, I am content but will go after 5 seconds!

You will notice the custom directive is on a child div as in my directive when I tried to use the element it was returning the comment produced by the `ng-if`. This is my directive

```
.directive('fadeAnimation', function ($animate) {
        'use strict';
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 800,
            link: function (scope, element) {

                scope.$watch('showPopover', function (newValue) {

                    console.log(scope.showPopover); // same as scope.showPopover in the controller

                    if (newValue === true) {    
                        $animate.addClass(element[0].parentNode, 'fade-animiate').then(function () {
                            $animate.removeClass(element[0].parentNode, 'fade-animiate');
                            //scope.showPopover = false;
                            // scope.$apply(); // this produces  Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
                        });

                    } else if (newValue === false) {
                        //scope.showPopover = false;
                        // scope.$apply(); // this produces  Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
                    }

                });
            }
        };
    });
```

As you can see I add and remove a CSS class (with animation) to the parent element. Once this is done I would like to set the scope.showPopover boolean that is in the controller to false as this prevents me having to double click the original link that toggles the popover (as it is false, we toggle to true, the animation hides the DIV but the `scope.showPopover` or `$scope.showPopover` is still true). I have tried setting `scope.showPopover = false` in my directive but this is not updated in the controller. When I try and force a scope.$apply(); I get an error in my console stating `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried setting this in the promise after I remove the css class and when I uncomment the `scope.showPopover = false` (in the `newValue === true` condition) the watch doesn't see this change and the watch breaks the next time I toggle the `$scope.showPopover` in the view. Nothing seems to work, I assume my approach is wrong! Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems you are using a shared scope, one issue I believe you are falling victim to is a prototypical inheritance problem when you are using a primitive of just "showPopover" vs following the "." rule of using objects (i.e. "vm.showPopover") .

Comment: Another solution is that if the "popover" has an isolate scope, you will need to pass the primitive objects into the directive through attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it fit with your requirement, i used animation hooks to trigger the fade:

**Javascript**

```
app.directive('fadeAnimation', function ($timeout) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.addClass('fade-animation');
        scope.$watch(attr.ngShow, function (value) {
            if(value){
              $timeout(function(){ scope.showPopover = false; },5000);
            }
        });
      }
  };
})
```

**CSS**:

```
.fade-animation.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.fade-animation.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  transition: all linear 1s;
}

.fade-animation {
   opacity: 1; 
}

.fade-animation.ng-hide {
   opacity: 0; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/pxO8Ruhl9Um4pJCyrK1t?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You should try using 2-way binding in your directive

HTML

```
<div ng-show="showPopover" class="popover" fade-animation show-popover="showPopover">Hello World, I am content but will go after 5 seconds!</div>
```

DIRECTIVE

```
    app.directive('fadeAnimation', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        showPopover: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.addClass('fade-animation');
        scope.$watch("showPopover", function(value) {
           if(value){
           //you should be able to flip the boolean here and see it in the controller                
           }
        });
      }
  };
});
```